# What is the correct way to do this using TDD principles?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, cross-platform

I'm new to TDD, and I'm trying to learn the right way to do things. So I have to make a javascript class for a web browser extension that stores the user's information to HTML5's `localStorage` (I'll call this class `UserInfoStorage`). However, I want to make my extension cross-browser compatible, and the way to interact with `localStorage` is different across the browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari).

Should I make another class called `Storage` that is specific for each browser and have `UserInfoStorage` use this to store stuff to `localStorage`? How would I unit-test this without tying the test for `UserInfoStorage` to the implementation of `Storage`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the best way to do this would be to create a test `Storage` that has a basic `get` and `set` functionality (kind of like a test database), and have `UserInfoStorage` use this to store and retrieve data. This allows for testing the interface of `UserInfoStorage` directly, without tying it to the implementation of `Storage`, so if I change the way `UserInfoStorage` works, the tests will still be valid (since they are not testing whether `UserInfoStorage` interacts with `Storage` correctly, but rather that the functions of `UserInfoStorage` produce the desired results).

Answer (score 2):

In general terms you would mock Storage under test to ensure that the UserInfoStorage interacts with it correctly. Those would comprise (part of) your unit tests on UserInfoStorage. Then you would have separate unit tests for each of the Storage implementations per browser, and ideally also tests on the code which determines which Storage implementation to provide according to the browser involved.